# retrofit 2 отмена запроса

Tags: android, retrofit

retrofit 2, в документации написано вы можете отменить запрос(call.cancel()) зачем это нужно отменять запрос? в каких местах она применяется, можно пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например переходите вы на другую активити, а запрос у вас не завершен и в методе onResponse у вас выполняются какие то действия связанные с данной активити. Если не завершить запрос, то в методе onResponse у вас может приложение упасть, т.к. объектов с которыми вы работаете могут не существовать.